# Unable to submit post to API Retrofit

Tags: java, android, http, retrofit

Actually i'm trying to send a txt file to a server using Retrofit.
But when i actually trying to send it it gives me the following error from onFailure method

I'm new in android and by looking on some tutorials on retrofit i can't still get what am i doing wrong and even if i'm using in right way retrofit, that would be great if someone will be able to help me.

> E/TAG: Unable to submit post to API.

But actually it's creating a folder on the server but not sending the file, what i'm doing wrong?

Here is my ApiUtils.java

```
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface APIService {

    @POST("UPD.aspx?CART=PTERM")
    Call<MyResponse> savePost(@Body RequestBody text);
}
```

Here is RetrofitClient.java

```
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class RetrofitClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Here is APIService.java

```
import okhttp3.MultipartBody;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Multipart;
import retrofit2.http.POST;
import retrofit2.http.Part;

public interface APIService {

    @Multipart
    @POST("UPD.aspx?CART=PTERM")
    Call<Void> savePost(@Part MultipartBody.Part text);
}
```

Here is sendPost() method which i use to send the file via onClick

```
public void sendPost() {
    File file = new File("/data/data/com.example.igardini.visualposmobile/files/scontrino.txt");

    MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder();
    builder.setType(MultipartBody.FORM);

    builder.addFormDataPart("scontrino", file.getName());

    MultipartBody requestBody = builder.build();

    APIService apiService = ApiUtils.getAPIService();

    Call<Void> call = apiService.savePost(requestBody);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

            } else {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("TAG", t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

And i'll appreciate if even someone will suggest me on how can i improve performance of retrofit with it's http requests.

Comment: In APIService.java class Call<Post> replace post with your response class

Comment: @Maitri oh right, i had even Post.java empty. How should i create the response class?

Comment: change name of that empty response class

Comment: @Maitri added to the question Post.java, what do you mean with response class? actually my server doesn't response anythink when i upload data to it so how can i do?

Comment: just create a blank java class for now like MyResponse.java

Comment: ok now Post.java is just an empty class as you can see on updated answer, but still unable to send that file...

Comment: I've posted a code.. Just try that

Comment: inside your `onFailure` change `Log.e("TAG", "Unable to submit post to API.");` to `Log.e("TAG", t.toString());` and check what is the error thrown

Comment: @NavneetKrishna getting 07-18 09:42:51.761 2168-2168/com.example.igardini.visualposmobile E/TAG: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $

Comment: what is your expected success response format(json)

Comment: @NavneetKrishna it's nothing i'm not getting a response so even in my API interface in Call<MyResponse> MyResponse.java is just an empty class

Comment: then make the call like this `Call<Void>` instead of `Call<MyResponse> ` see edited answer

Comment: @NavneetKrishna updated my Answer with new used code, the folder on server is created but no file in it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176226/discussion-between-johnkarry-and-navneet-krishna).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Void instead of empty class

```
public void sendPost(MultipartBody.Part txt) {
mAPIService.savePost(txt).enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {

        if(response.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.i("TAG", "post submitted to API." + response.body().toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Unable to submit post to API.");
    }
});
}
```

**`Request body`**

```
RequestBody fbody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/*"), file); 
builder.addFormDataPart("scontrino", file.getName(),fbody);
```

Comment: Ok i'm not getting anymore errors but still the file is not sent, it's creating the folder on the server but no file in it

Comment: check if `response.isSuccessful()` is true

Comment: That's the response i get Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=http://MyServerIP/WebQuery/UPD.aspx?CART=PTERM}

Comment: i think you are not passing the file try this, `RequestBody fbody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/*"), file); builder.addFormDataPart("scontrino", file.getName(),fbody);`

Comment: replace `builder.addFormDataPart("scontrino", file.getName());` with that

Answer (score 1):

```
private void sendPost() {

    MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder();
    builder.setType(MultipartBody.FORM);

    builder.addFormDataPart("scontrino", file.getName());

    MultipartBody requestBody = builder.build();

    MainInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(MainInterface.class);

    Call<MyResponse> call = apiService.savePost(requestBody);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<MyResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MyResponse> call, Response<MyResponse> response) {
            progressBarHandler.dismiss();
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

            } else {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MyResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```